# Why Symfony $tokenstorage is empty after JWT Authentication

Tags: symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I get no current User by requests from websocket to symfony backend.

i authenticate my User through route `/authapi/v1/applogin` manual with following:

```
if($passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $content->password)){
  $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
  $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
  //$session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
  $this->session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
  $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        
  $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token); //UsernamePasswordToken

  //$JWTManager = 
  return new JsonResponse(['jwt' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
}
```

at this point, the user is logged in and $tokenStorage has the User Object by requests using postman.

now i want to sent a request from a websocket subdomain with authorization header `Bearer myjwt token` using axios. Here, the $tokenStorage is null. This means that jwt isnt authenticated fully? what is missing in the auth part?

Comment: Are you using CORS or other security mechanism? Any errors in the javascript console? What's your firewall configuration? Is it stateful?

Comment: its going through the main firewall. i added stateless: true and now some things work. Others not. I test around it but maybe thats do the trick. Its so, i need to add a new firewall with stateless true and own url pattern for requests from node server?

Comment: As you can see in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context), a stateful firewall relies on the user session, while `stateless` do not, they re-authenticate each request. Depending on your `framework.session` configuration, the different subdomains can be preventing your browser from sending session information. That could be a way to do it, maybe you can tweak the config, add another authenticator... Depends on the app, but I'd say yes, you can start by splitting the firewalls.

Comment: I tested the whole night and thats exactly the problem. I have splitted the firewall and now all worked as expected. Many Thx for your ideas and help. For People who have the same problem i create an example here later.